Error when performing the merge() of two ImageCollections
I have two imageCollections, one from Sentinel 1 and one from Sentinel 2. I would like to perform the merge specifically of both collections to perform a classification later.
However, when I use .merge() I get an error saying that the bands are incompatible. I have already converted to float and still get the same error

s12: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image
with incompatible bands was encountered:   First image type: 2 bands
([VV, VH]). Current image type: 4 bands ([B2, B3, B4, B8]).
Image ID: 20200104T135109_20200104T135107_T21KYT Some bands might require explicit casts.

my code
var poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
[[-54.78753991320279,-20.76018247385302],
[-54.44421715929654,-20.76018247385302],
[-54.44421715929654,-20.528863542361954],
[-54.78753991320279,-20.528863542361954],
[-54.78753991320279,-20.76018247385302]])

Map.addLayer(poly, {}, 'poly')
Map.centerObject(poly, 10)

// Load Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 Image Collections
var s1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(poly)
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
.select(['VV', 'VH'])
.map(function(image){
  return image.float()})
.map(function(img){
  return img.clip(poly)
});

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterBounds(poly)
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'])
.map(function(image){
  return image.float()})
.map(function(img){
  return img.clip(poly)
});

var resample = function (image){
return image.resample('bilinear').reproject({
crs: s2.first().projection().crs(),
scale: 10})}


var s1r = s1.map(resample)
var s2r = s2.map(resample)


Map.addLayer(s1r, {}, 's1r')
Map.addLayer(s2r, {}, 's2r')

   var s12 = s1r.merge(s2r)
print(s12, 's12')

Map.addLayer(s12, {}, 's12')

note update
I edited my code in order to avoid the GEE memory limitation problem, in addition, I am using float which is more suitable than int32 precisely because of the memory usage.
update 2
key commom

//add key function
var addWeeks = function(image) {
var referenceDate = ee.Date('1970-01-01');
var weeks = image.date().difference(referenceDate, 'day').divide(7);
return image.set('weeks_since_reference', weeks);
};
                    
var s1k = s1r.map(addWeeks)
var s2k = s2r.map(addWeeks)

var s12k = s1k.combine(s2k, true)

print(s12k, 's12')

but I still get a blank collection as a result

merge() sticks two collections together "end-to-end" (the result has the same number of elements as the length of both collections summed), so the bands in both collections must match. You probably want combine() instead, which interlaces the bands.

I used .combine() instead of .merge(), in var s12 = s1r.combine(s2r), but I got a blank ImageCollection, without any elements.

update: I added a key property (weeks from Unix date 1970-01-01) to both collections, to be used by .combine() to join the two collections, but I still get a blank collection as a result. I also tried var s12 = s1k.combine(s2k, true), where s1k and s2k represent the collections with the common key.
